# Declare struct and struct-size related arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm working in a condition like this:

```
typedef struct __type_x{
   sub_type_a  a;
   sub_type_b  b;
   sub_type_c  c;
}type_x_t;

uint32_t type_x_uids[] = {
   1, //a's_uid
   2, //b's_uid
   3, //c's_uid
};

uint32_t type_x_uid_another[] = {
   3, //a's uid in another API system
   1, //b's uid in another API system
   2, //c's uid in another API system
};

uint32_t type_x_uids_one_more[] = {
   1, //a's_uid in yet another system
   3, //b's_uid in yet another system
   2, //c's_uid in yet another system
};
```

The problem is: If I need to add one more data(like d) into struct `type_x_t`, I need to add its uids into all other three arrays.

It is hard to maintain the code.

So I'm wondering if it is possible to maintain all these data from four places into one table?

I can put three uint32 arrays into one 2D array

```
uint32_t uid[system_id][value];
```

but I also have to maintain two pieces of code instead of one.

I'm wondering if there is anyway I can move forward? Therefore I can maintain one table to manage all these data. Such like

```
{#data_type, #data_name, #uid_1, #uid2, #uid 3},
```

Trying to use Macro to solve the problem, but I cannot access the data in certain position by `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: You have typos in your question I think. `uint32_t` --> `type_x_t`

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. There may be solutions in one that don't work in the other.

Comment: "but I also have to maintain two pieces of code instead of one." What do you mean with that?

Comment: @cdhowie c code. c++ also acceptance for self study, but may not use it in the project.

Comment: @kaylum no it is uint32_t.  `the defination of data`, `the data's uid`

Comment: `__type_x` I don't think you're allowed to call something like this.

Comment: @AdrianMaire It means if I want to add one more element in my type_x_t, I also need to add the corresponding element in the uid arrays, which is not maintainable-friendly, if some other people try to add a new element in the struct, he may forget to add corresponding uids in the array. Though I can to some check to avoid the problem, I'm still wondering if I can put the struct declaration and uid array declaration into one table/macro/function or whatever.

Comment: Well then `uint32_t type_x_uids = {}` makes no sense. You cannot init a single uint32_t with a compound initialiser like that.

Comment: @kaylum  oops, my fault. forgot to add [], it should be uint32_t type_x_uids[] = {}

Comment: @kaylum yes you are right. It is not my real code, I don't do both of them at the same time. I just want to show one possible solution here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have placed the code adjacently in one single file, you are actually maintaining one place and not several. What you have is not necessarily bad. Anyway...

I will assume there's a reason why `type_x_t` is a struct and not an array. Then clearly the best design is to add the "uid" for "a" to the `sub_type_a` struct, or alternatively make a new struct containing both, since those data belong together.

If that's not an option, you could go with the array and then put that inside the `type_x_t` struct.

If that's not an option either, consider some completely different program design.

With all program design options exhausted, then - and only then - you could consider macros. What you are fishing for is so-called "X macros", which is the last resort and not really recommended, since they make the code much harder to read. The purpose of X macros is to centralize code maintenance of data to one place. It goes like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define TYPE_X_LIST \
  X(a,1,3,1)        \
  X(b,2,1,3)        \
  X(c,3,2,2)

typedef struct
{
  #define X(name, dummmy1, dummy2, dummy3) sub_type_##name name;
  TYPE_X_LIST
  #undef X
} type_x_t;

uint32_t type_x_uids[] = {
  #define X(dummy1, id, dummy2, dummy3) id,
  TYPE_X_LIST
  #undef X
};

uint32_t type_x_uid_another[] = {
  #define X(dummy1, dummy2, id, dummy3) id,
  TYPE_X_LIST
  #undef X
};

uint32_t type_x_uids_one_more[] = {
  #define X(dummy1, dummy2, dummy3, id) id,
  TYPE_X_LIST
  #undef X
};
```

Now you only have to change the "TYPE_X_LIST" when you need to change the data. If you want to keep track of how many data sets you have, you can add an enum to count them:

```
typedef enum
{
  #define X(name, ...) something_##name,
  TYPE_X_LIST
  #undef X
  TYPE_X_N  // the number of data sets
} type_x_size_t;
```

Then `TYPE_X_N` could be used to set array sizes etc.

Comment: the reason `type_x_t` is a struct and not an array is that its elements do not share the same type...

Comment: @lanyusea Are they wildly different types then, not in the slightest related to each other? Otherwise this looks like a typical case to use polymorphism.

Comment: yes they are wildly different types. well, now i think my question may be too weird and not typical :(